Is a schedule daily()->at() in Laravel 8 taking at() into account?
I have this code:
$schedule->command('end:tracking:day')->daily()->at('00:05');

Would that run the job at 0:00 (22:00 UTC because the app timezone is Europe/Amsterdam and wie are in Daylight Saving time, UTC+2) or at 22:05?
Logs indicate it runs at 22:00, but I am not sure if I am looking at the right logs.
There is this example in the docs:
weekly()->mondays()->at('13:00');

Looking at the code for this methods did not make me much smarter :-)
Which seems like the job should run at 22:05 instead of 22:00 so I probably look at the wrong logs?

Yes, it should work as expected.
This job would run at 22:05
I was looking at the wrong logs i.e. there was some crazy mess-up with the crontab which was pointing to an old app version.
